# How to check if column in SQL SERVER is auto increment in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, increment

I have a problem where I have to insert some data into table in SQL SERVER, from my C# program, but I don't know which columns are auto increment? Is there any way on how to find these columns so I don't insert values into those columnns?

Comment: You mean, like inspecting `sys.columns` and checking the value of `is_identity`?

Comment: Ideally you should know the schema of the table you are inserting into in the first place

Comment: I just have to know index of the column which is auto increment so I don't insert that value

Comment: @AlmaIbrašimović Not the Auto Increment Column, but the Primary Key one. A integer with Autoincrement is the obvious solution. But GUID's tend to be non-sequential. If you try to insert it, the SQL Server will sternly reject the INSERT statement. It is also usually the 1st Column or the one that most screams "Hey, I should be a Primary Key Candidate".

Comment: Note that often more then one Column has restraints. Foreign Key Constraints are common. Other columns might be unique. And then there is RowVersion wich is also non-setable.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a C# operation. This is the kind of operation that can only be done reliably in the DBMS. The tables being setup properly and staying setup properly is the DB Adminsitrators job. Maybe the job of your instaler programm. Know the shema, do not try to "guess" it.

I do not think it is worthwhile to spend resources on verifying this. I do check if a retreiving of the Passwrod Hash & salt by username returns more then result (while Name might not be a PK, it should still be unique), but beyond that the DB is simply something I have to trust. It acting unexpectedly is like the RAM acting unexpectedly - there is nothing you can do to fix it and detection is a Administrators job.

You can either trust nearly everything of the DB, or you simply can not trust the DB.

Comment: I have to load excel sheet into program and then load that data into DB, but I don't know the structure of the DB, I just have name of the table, columns and data. So if I am inserting into table with column which is auto increment, my program doesn't know that so I can't insert

Comment: What is preventing you from talking to a DBA to get the details?

Comment: @AlmaIbrašimović Then figure out the structure. It is a DB you have access too. Why not simply ask for the Shema? Usually the shema is given in "CREATE TABLE"  Syntax: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language | I think at best you could get the Column Names. But figuring out the PK's? That you get from a shema. Entity Framework is about building classes for your DB access at runtime. So I think it has some solution to some of that.